# git show commit in beyond compare

Tags: git, beyondcompare, git-diff

I would like to see a specific commit in Beyond Compare or any other separate diff tool while viewing it via `git show`. I tried looking at help of git show/difftool/config but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how it can be done?

I've looked at [Git Diff with Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069490/git-diff-with-beyond-compare) and configured Beyond Compare for `git difftool` but I also want to use it as tool from `git show`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to use `git difftool` to see commits that I normally used to see via `git show`.

`git show $commit` translates to `git difftool $commit^ $commit`.

The above command shows difference between commit's parent ($commit^) and commit. All this is of course after configuring Beyond Compare with difftool.

Comment: `git show $commit` is not equivalent to `git difftool $commit^ $commit` if we are reviewing a merge commit. git show presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by `git diff-tree --cc $commit`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show

Answer (score 13):

You can also create an alias "showtool" to wrap the call to `git difftool`:

```
set +o histexpand
git config --global alias.showtool "! sh -c 'if [ -z \$1 ]; then REVISION="HEAD"; else REVISION="\$1"; fi; git difftool \$REVISION~ \$REVISION' -"
```

.. then you can execute:

```
git showtool 81e945b
```

.. or just

```
git showtool
```

.. as a shortcut for `git difftool 81e945b~1 81e945b` to show the changes introduced in `81e945b` using the configured difftool, or in the second case `git difftool HEAD~1 HEAD`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I extended it to work also without parameter like git show does: set +o histexpand; git config --global alias.showtool "!sh -c 'if [ -z \$1 ]; then REVISION="HEAD"; else REVISION="\$1"; fi; git difftool \$REVISION~ \$REVISION\' -"

Comment: Thanks Tomáš, I like that enhancement and have adopted it and edited the solution above.  I found one stray backslash in your code, the last one before the closing ', so please check.

Comment: I have expanded this on [git-showtool repo](https://github.com/albfan/git-showtool) to support commands like `$ git showtool -y :/my\ commit\ message`

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a diff tool set up, like the awesome p4merge, you can do this:

```
git diff HEAD HEAD~1
```

Works like a charm.

Similarly if you want to see the commit before that, you can do:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD~2
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me nicely, to show the diff of the last commit

```
git difftool HEAD~ HEAD
```

For other commits you can replace `HEAD` with commit hash eg:

```
git difftool 1234ABCD~ 1234ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that git show is based on the tool set in the GIT_PAGER variable. I don't use Beyond Compare but i think that you can try something like this:

```
$ GIT_PAGER='bc3' git show <whatever>
```

Maybe you should fill the GIT_PAGER variable with some additional parameter that allows bc3 process the input.

There are more suitable ways to persist the pager. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136178/git-diff-handling-long-lines) can give you more tips about how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @javabrett answer I have created

https://github.com/albfan/git-showtool

to support commands like

```
$ git showtool -y :/my\ commit\ message
```