# Still a problem with Git after installing MacOS Mojave

Tags: git, macos, include

I recently upgraded my MacOS to Mojave, and now I have found that Git doesn't work. I continue to get the following error message when I try to initialize a new git repo on my machine:

```
error: could not expand include path '~/.gitcinclude'
fatal: bad config line 44 in file /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig
```

Here are lines 43-46 of the `gitconfig` file on my machine:

```
[include]
    path = ~/.gitcinclude
    path = .githubconfig
    path = .gitcredential
```

I followed the advice from another stackOverflow question ([Git is not working after macOS Mojave Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-devel)), but Git still refuses to work. Specifically, I ran the following to upgrade xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I then re-set the path to the xcode folder:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Any suggestions as to where I should go from here?

Comment: What is on line 44 of /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig? Is the HOME environment variable set in the process that is running git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Could not expand include path '~/.gitcinclude', fatal: bad config file line 49 in /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908041/git-could-not-expand-include-path-gitcinclude-fatal-bad-config-file-line)

Comment: What versions of Xcode / of git do you have ? After upgrading to 10.14 Mojave, I downloaded Xcode 11.3.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads (7 GB), then `Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.dmg` installed `/usr/bin/git` -> `git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)`

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The second answer from another stackOverflow question did the trick. I missed it in my previous search because this question doesn't specifically address MacOS problems.

[Git Could not expand include path '~/.gitcinclude', fatal: bad config file line 49 in /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908041/git-could-not-expand-include-path-gitcinclude-fatal-bad-config-file-line)