# How do I edit the gitconfig file?

Tags: git, git-config

I am trying to download a software package on the terminal, but I am getting the following error:

```
error: could not expand include path '~/.gitcinclude'

fatal: bad config line 44 in file /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig
```

The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908041/git-could-not-expand-include-path-gitcinclude-fatal-bad-config-file-line) requires that I edit the gitconfig file. I am completely new to all of this, so I am not sure how to go about editing this file. I have tried using nano to edit the file, but when I try to write out, I get the message "Permission denied". Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `sudo nano` to remedy "Permission Denied".

Comment: Is the HOME environment variable set? If you're using Bash, post the output of `declare -p HOME`. See the [second answer on the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42179879/4518341), which is a better solution.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You can [edit] the question to add details.

Comment: you have not permission to write or overwrite the file
you must run nano with sudo or change file permision to write by this command:
chmod a+w file

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! sudo nano worked!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach before editing the system file `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig` is to check if adding the missing file is enough.

That assumes `$HOME` is properly set, as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/phpro/grumphp/issues/105#issuecomment-413120003):

```
touch $HOME/.gitcinclude
```